# C# calculate a single column in ListView and display it in a Label

Tags: c#, listview, label, data-conversion

I have a ListView that I can export and import successfully.  My problem is that I need to calculate the payment column (last column in the ListView) and display the results in a Label.  However, I'm getting an "input string was not in correct format" error.

Here is my code:

```
private void DisplayWeeklyEarnings()
    {
        decimal total =0;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvTimeSheet.Items)
        {
            total += Convert.ToDecimal(item.SubItems[4].Text);
        }

        lblEarnings.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", total);
    }
```

I also tried:

```
total += Decimal.Parse(item.Subitems[4].Text);
```

Other have suggested using:

```
total += Decimal.Parse(item.Subitems(4).Text);
```

However, that give me an error about using Subitems as a method. So obviously that's wrong.

Here is my form face:
[Click here to see the Form Face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dv2d.png)

Here is the form with pay column populated:
[Click here to see the Populated form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN0b0.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last column contains the currency symbol. This could be parsed if you use the proper overload of decimal.Parse

```
 total += decimal.Parse(item.SubItems[4].Text, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

In case your last column contains a value that cannot be parsed neither with this overload of decimal.Parse (like for example a blank value) then consider to use

```
decimal d;    
if(decimal.TryParse(item.SubItems[4].Text, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out d))
    total += d;
```

TryParse is more fail safe if you don't have a total control of the input because it doesn't raise an exception in case of malformed input.

Comment: The first one worked great.  Thank you for your help.